# highcharts-vue xAxis.tickPositioner with series.data.length == 0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

.I use highcharts-vue and xAxis.tickPositioner function

```js
chartOptions: {
  chart: {
    type: 'areaspline'
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function () {
      let positions = [],        
          tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
          increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 10)

      if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
          for (tick; tick  <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
              positions.push(tick)
          }
      }
      return positions
    }  
  },
  series: [],
  categories: []
}

mounted(){
  this.chartOptions.series = [
    {name: 'test1', data: [1]},
    {name: 'test2', data: [2]}
  ]
  this.chartOptions.xAxis.categories = ['category1']
}
```

```html
<highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
```

I need it because ussualy I have a lot of data point.
It works good If this.chartOptions.series[i].data.length > 1.
But if this.chartOptions.series[i].data.length == 1 - browser is crashed.
What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by this changes:

```js
tickPositioner: function () {
  let positions = [],        
      tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
      increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 10)

  if (this.dataMax === 0) {
    positions = [0]
  } else if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
      for (tick; tick  <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
        positions.push(tick)
      }
  }
  return positions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for one point all your variables (tick, increment, dataMax) are equal 0, so as a consequence this `for` is an infinity loop.

You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/35suo8k0/

As a solution you can use this code:

```
  xAxis: {
    tickPositioner() {
      let positions = [],
        tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
        increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 10)

      if (this.dataMax && this.dataMin) {
        for (tick; tick <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
          positions.push(tick)
        }
      }
      return positions
    }
  },
```

I changed the if condition - now it checks if the dataMax and dataMin exist.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k6vj9af8/

Comment: Thank You for answer! Your solution works, but in this case positions wilд be still empty [], so there will be no label on xAxis. But i want see lebel for my one point. My solution is below